# How debug the clear button and get it to reset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in asp.net c# mvc 4.0. I believe I have an event handler problem. On the site, the clear button is supposed to reset all the items, however, all but one does not reset. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you post the code that is not behaving properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Controller, have you tried ViewState.Clear()? You can update the model all you want but if the ViewState is not cleared, the values will remain.